# All my commits have the same time

Tags: git, time, git-commit

As I just pushed my commits to GitHub, the website told my that the last update was 5 hours ago. I figured out the problem was local and that my commits were wrongly timestamped.

In the printscreen below, you can see that the dates and times on the right are exactly the same (I know I program fast, but not that much).

As you can see in the lower part, the *Author* is me with that enigmatic petrified time, but the *Committer*, although it's still me, has the normal time at which the commit has been made.
[image: Same time in git]

I don't want to manually update the wrong times, mostly because it's already pushed and that I don't really care about 5 hours, but what can I do to fix the problem from now on?

As someone will obviously ask me to check my system time, now that I did and that it matches the *Committer* time (i.e. the good one).

## Edit

The problem solved itself just like <strike>magic</strike> softwares. I still want to know why it happened, but I don't know how to reproduce the bug.

Comment: That's strange. If the committer times were all the same, it could be easily explained, because the committer time updates when you do a rebase. But author times all being the same is indeed strange.

Comment: I know. And I didn't do any rebase. It's plain linear commits. I used a branch that I fast-forwarded, but I don't see how it could have changed anything.

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: I'm using git version `2.9.3.windows.1` and git-gui version `0.20.GITGUI`.